# AWS Android sdk 1.7.1.1 not compiling - issues with AmazonHttpClient and HttpClientFactory

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

I downloaded the latest version, 1.7.1.1, added it as a module in Intellij, and added it as a dependency in my project. Building it against Android API 17. When building, the AmazonHttpClient and HttpClientFactory classes give a few compile errors.

For example, in AmazonHTTPClient.java,

```
SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(
            SSLContext.getDefault(),
            SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

is not an applicable constructor.

Also, httpClient.setRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved, and the Scheme constructors have their parameters in the wrong order.

Is this an Amazon issue or is something wrong on my end?

Comment: I've encountered the same problem with v2.1 detailed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894513/building-the-android-aws-2-1-0-sdk

But, for v1.x, can't you just use Maven with the packaged pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was how I was adding it in Intellij - it should have been added as a project dependency rather than module.