# Building the Android AWS 2.1.0 SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, amazon-web-services

We've hit the DEX function call limit on Android (seems to be a common problem when using AWS for Android) so one work-around I'm trying to implement is to build the AWS SDK locally, and strip out a lot of the content we don't need (and there's a lot we don't need...).

But I am having two specific issues

1) Unlike v1.x there is no packaged pom.xml file in the v2.x repository, so I can't use Maven

2) The AWS Android SDK seems to use the public release of Apache httpclient and httpcore, which provide functions unavailable in the Android SDK (we need to support Android-10 and up)

Building in Eclipse, this results in the errors in the following places

- HttpClientFactory.java

  - The method setRedirectStrategy(HttpClientFactory.LocationHeaderNotRequiredRedirectStrategy)
    is undefined for the type SdkHttpClient
  - The constructor Scheme(String, int, PlainSocketFactory) is undefined
  - The constructor SSLSocketFactory(SSLContext, X509HostnameVerifier) is undefined
  - The constructor Scheme(String, int, SSLSocketFactory) is undefined
  - The constructor BasicScheme(ChallengeState) is undefined
  - AUTH_CACHE cannot be resolved or is not a field
- MetricInputStreamEntity.java

  - The constructor InputStreamEntity(InputStream, long, ContentType) is undefined

All these errors are cases where the API exists in the public Apache release, but not the Android SDK version of Apache (which is V4.0 I think).

Promoting httpclient and httpcore above the Android SDK allows the code to compile but generates the following error when trying to run our test app

> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.

Clearly, Google are telling me, strongly, not to do this.

So, how are you meant to build the Android v2.1.0 SDK?

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Hey sorry to hear you're having issues. Are you hitting the limit despite using ProGuard? If not, I'd recommend trying that as it's much simpler than trying to compile the SDK yourself. You can turn off obfuscation in ProGuard while you are still in the development cycle so it doesn't get in the way of debugging. This issue is something we are aware of and actively working on fixing. If you still want to try to build it yourself then I will do my best to help but that's probably a last resort

Comment: Thanks for the comment Richard, I went towards building the SDK myself because v1.x was so easy to download and build.  TBH I've moved away from this and started looking at other solutions.  Our problem with using ProGuard (which is more than possible) is that we'll have to run it on all configurations (dev and production) which will seriously impact our turnaround time.  We've updated to 2.1.0 which seems to have a reduction in methods (from 2.0.5), and we're looking to strip out other SDKs until there's a more suitable solution available.  Any idea when a fix might be available?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have a good estimate but we are in the process of planning out the coming months so I'll do my best to try and push for this feature to be included. I'm glad you got the issue resolved though!